# JavaFX lags and sometimes freezes my Mac, How can I fix it?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

So I recently downloaded and installed JDK 9.0.1 on my Mac to use JavaFX since JavaFX doesn't work on JDK 11 (Right?), it lags so much and sometimes freezes the laptop and I have to restart my laptop every time it freezes, anyone knows how to fix this issue? And also I'm new to Mac, I tried googling but I didn't get a proper solution​.

Comment: Do you mean that running JavaFX application freezes Mac or even editing code is slow?

Comment: Editing the code, like I can't create a JavaFX application, it freezes.

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack attaching logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Hey, should I try the JavaFX SDK by gluon? I downloaded it but I'm do not know how to install it.

Comment: What makes you thing JavaFX doesn't work with JDK 11? You just have to add it as a dependency to your project, like any other dependency, since the JavaFX modules were removed from the JDK in Java 11. See https://openjfx.io/ for more info.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it works or not, that's exactly why I said "(right?)".